# Who are not tempted by Satan?

Tags: quran, tafseer, shaitan

In the Quran there are some verses which show the humans are not tempted by Satan, such as:

> "قَالَ رَبِّ بِمَآ أَغْوَيْتَنِي لأُزَيِّنَنَّ لَهُمْ فِي الأَرْضِ
>   وَلأُغْوِيَنَّهُمْ أَجْمَعِينَ إِلاَّ عِبادَکَ مِنْهُمُ الْمُخْلَصينَ
>
> «He said, My Lord, since You have lured me away, I will glamorize for
>   them on earth, and I will lure them all away Except for Your sincere
>   servants among them»**39-40 Hijr**

And

> «انه لیس له سلطان علی الذین امنوا و علی ربهم یتوکلون
>
> He has no authority over those who believe and trust in their
>   Lord.».**99 Nahl**

Who are these persons and how we can find the answer of this question by reviewing other verses of the Quran?

Comment: "who believe and trust in their Lord" - That's the answer.  They are the believers who trust in their Lord.

Comment: In this order -> [43:36](http://quran.com/43/36) [33:41](http://quran.com/33/41) and [7:201](http://quran.com/7/201)

Comment: Exactly that as @Sayyid has expalined and azam has given references to. But Satan can't tempt Prophets at any case and can tempt people other than Prophets when they do not possess the goods explained in the Ayyah you have given.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                  In the name of Allah
```

As another related verse of the holy Quran: it mentions that everybody would be misled except "Mukhlasin":

> قَالَ فَبِعِزَّتِكَ لَأُغْوِيَنَّهُمْ أَجْمَعِينَ ﴿٨٢﴾ إِلَّا
>   عِبَادَكَ مِنْهُمُ الْمُخْلَصِينَ ﴿٨٣﴾ /  ص
>
> [Iblees] said, "By your might, I will surely mislead them all (82)
>   Except, among them, Your chosen servants." (83)

**But who can be considered as Mukhlasin?**

It is narrated from Imam Sadiq (a.s.) as the sixth Imam of shi’a that:

> Everyone would be destroyed (by Satan) except the individuals who know
>   (what deeds are good or not) and perform what they know as well, and
>   as the most significant point: they have sincerity in their deeds …
>   (Sincerity means practicing for the sake of Allah, and taking action
>   for the sake of Allah not for people and position and …)

Or it is narrated that prophet Isa told his students:

> be fasting, but lubricate your lips that people don’t figure out that
>   you are fasting.  (Oh, yeah, it can be named Ikhlas (sincerity))

**Reference:**

- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/38:82)
- [www.ham85.blogfa.com](http://www.ham85.blogfa.com/cat-3.aspx)
- [www.ya3man3fid.blogfa.com](http://www.ya3man3fid.blogfa.com/post-36.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Allah in Quran and His prophet taught us some act of worship that made Satan far from us. From them there is:

1/ The Prophet said " Who said: There is no god but Allah, alone with no partner, He own everything, to Him the praise, which is over all things and he can do everything, a hundred times in a day will have The reward of who 10 man, and will have 100 Goods and will be forgiven for 100 sins, **and those words will be preserve him from the devil that day until the evening**"

2/ Ayat al Qursi (AlBaqara/255) The prophet used to read it before sleeping and he said who read this AYA before he sleep God will send a protector for him and no Satan will go near to him until he wake up

3/ The last tow AYET from surat Al-Baqara the Prophet also used to read them before sleeping and he said if someone read those ayet in a night, they will protect him

4/ The Prophet also said "Who do salet al fajr in a group will be in the protection of God" 
From this we conclude that persons who truly believe in God and worship him alone and always remember that there is no god but Allah will be blessed by many thing among them He will make them close to him and Satan will fear them and will not have the power to approach them and tempt them

Answer (score -1):

Satan can't tempt 
1. Prophets in any case and at any cost.
2. Those people who gave their will to Allah and spend life as Allah says and commands them. Many references are in Quran.

Comment: Do you mean he can't tempt or if he does, he won't succeed?